# Number of assembly instruction execution orders

Tags: multithreading, math, assembly, language-agnostic, combinatorics

I am working on a presentation on multithreading and I want to demonstrate how instructions can increase in a factorially large way.

Consider the trivial program

```
a++;
b++;
c++;
```

In a single-threaded program the three assembly instructions (read, add one, write) that make up the `++` operation only has one order (read a, add one to a, write a to memory, read b,...)

In a program with just three threads executing these three lines in parallel there are many more configurations. The compiler can optimize and re-write these instruction in any order  with the constraint that 'read', 'add one' and 'write' occur in order for `a` `b` and `c`. How many valid orders are there?

Initial thoughts:
(3+3+3)!* 1/(3!+3!+3!)=20160

where (3+3+3)! is the total number of permutations without constraint and 1/(3!+3!+3!) is the proportion of permutations that have the correct order.

Comment: If you are trying to do things in parallel then thread 0 has three choices, handle a, b, or c.  thread 1 then is left with 2, thread 2 left with 1, 3*2*1 = 6 different ways this can be handled.  It doesnt really get interesting until you do something with a, b, or c, and then start to mix a, b, c  d = a+b.  e=d+c.

Comment: What you're describing is superscalar, not multi-threaded. Specifically it's superscalar with out of order execution. In a multi threaded environment there is exactly one premutation that the compiler compiles to: `read, add, write`.

Comment: What has "the compiler" to do with "multithreading"? This is a rather confused question. It's in *single* threading that the question of how this code can be compiled becomes interesting, but the in-CPU instruction reordering is a far more interesting aspect. In multithreading, you cannot in general put *any* order on instructions that execute in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be more of a elaborate comment but...

In the single thread version the compiler can reorder those additions with out the change in the output. `c++` compilers are allowed to do so. So there is `3!` possibilities for the single thread. And that is assuming the `++` is atomic.

When you go into multithreading the sense of order of operations loses its meaning, depending on architecture it can be done in precisely at the same time. In fact you do not even have threads. E.g. SSE instructions.

What you are trying to count is executing 3 additions where `load->inc->store` are not atomic, on a single thread. IMO, the way to impose order on the total of 9 elements would be similar to yours, but the factor would be `(3!*3!*3!)`.

1st you take 9! then you impose order on 3 elements by dividing it by 3!, and then repeat process 2 more times. However I get the feeling that this factor is too big.

I would ask a mathematician that's good with combinatorics. The equivalent question is, having `NxM` coloured balls. `N` is the number of variables, `M` is the number of atomic operations you need to execute on each. What is the number of different orders for the balls. The colour is the variable. Because you know that 1st of a colour must be the `load`, 2nd `++` and 3rd `store`. So you get `M=3` balls for each of `N=3` colours. Maybe this representation would be better for a pure mathematician.

EDIT: Well apparently according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#In_combinatorics) on permutations of multisets my initial guess was right. Still I would check myself.